# 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Connection'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, epplus, sqlconnection

I am trying to import and excel file into my sql database using Epplus library in MVC5 and Entity framework 6 in C#. I am getting this error. I know there is something not right the way I am getting my connection string.

I am getting the error on the await new bulkwriter line on 'Connection'

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> StructureAsync(FormCollection postedFile)
    {
        var usersList = new List<bomStructuredImportTgt>();
        if (Request != null)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["postedFile"];
            if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
            {
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
                byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                var data = file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file.InputStream))
                {
                    var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                    var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                    var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                    var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                    for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
                    {
                        var user = new bomStructuredImportTgt();
                        user.ACTUAL_DATE = Convert.ToDateTime(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value);
                        user.DESCRIPTION = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value?.ToString();
                        user.LEVEL = Convert.ToInt32(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 3].Value);
                        user.PARENT_PARTNO = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 4].Value?.ToString();
                        user.PART_NO = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 5].Value?.ToString();
                        user.PART_NAME = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 6].Value?.ToString();
                        user.HNS = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 7].Value?.ToString();
                        user.DWGSZ = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 8].Value?.ToString();
                        user.PART = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 9].Value?.ToString();
                        user.L1QTY = Convert.ToInt32(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 10].Value);
                        user.COLORM = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 11].Value?.ToString();
                        user.ATTCD = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 12].Value?.ToString();
                        user.KD = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 13].Value?.ToString();
                        user.SELL = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 14].Value?.ToString();
                        user.PL_GROUP = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 15].Value?.ToString();
                        user.PL1 = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 16].Value?.ToString();
                        user.AT1 = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 17].Value?.ToString();
                        user.PL2 = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 18].Value?.ToString();
                        user.AT2 = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 19].Value?.ToString();
                        user.PL3 = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 20].Value?.ToString();
                        user.PLANT = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 21].Value?.ToString();
                        user.SHRPCMINMAX = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 22].Value?.ToString();
                        usersList.Add(user);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        using (SqlConnection excelImportDBEntities = new SqlConnection("Dev_Purchasing_New_ModelEntities"))
        {

            await new BulkWriter().InsertAsync(usersList, "bomStructuredImportTgt", excelImportDBEntities.Database.Connection, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        return View("Structure");
    }

  public class BulkWriter
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping[]> ColumnMapping =
            new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping[]>();

        public async Task InsertAsync<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string bomStructuredImportTgt, SqlConnection excelImportDBEntities,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using (var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(excelImportDBEntities))
            using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(items))
            {
                bulk.DestinationTableName = bomStructuredImportTgt;
                foreach (var colMap in GetColumnMappings<T>())
                    bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(colMap);
                await bulk.WriteToServerAsync(reader, cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping> GetColumnMappings<T>() =>
            ColumnMapping.GetOrAdd(typeof(T),
                type =>
                    type.GetProperties()
                        .Select(p => new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(p.Name, p.Name)).ToArray());
    }
```

I have a class BulkWriter which is used to bulk copy the records in the sql. I wanted to use this class for my code to be time efficient.

Comment: What is `Dev_Purchasing_New_ModelEntities`? If it is the name of the connection string in `web.config` then you should retrieve it by yourself: `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dev_Purchasing_New_ModelEntities"]`

Comment: yes it is the name in the connection string\

Comment: like this?  using (SqlConnection excelImportDBEntities = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dev_Purchasing_New_ModelEntities"])
            {

                await new BulkWriter().InsertAsync(usersList, "bomStructuredImportTgt", excelImportDBEntities.Database.Connection, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            return View("Structure");

Comment: As to why you're getting that specific error, `excelImportDBEntities.Database` is a `string` type. `string`s don't have a `Connection` property.

Comment: I have tried like this as well, var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dev_Purchasing_New_ModelEntities"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection excelImportDBEntities = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
               
                await new BulkWriter().InsertAsync(usersList, "bomStructuredImportTgt", ((excelImportDBEntities).Database.Connection), CancellationToken.None);
            }

Comment: @BrootsWaymb So what should i do?

Comment: @Minhal - Well to get rid of this particular error, you won't be able to do `excelImportDBEntities.Database.Connection`, it's just not possible. It would be like doing `"my new string".Connection`. It simply doesn't make sense, given the type.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb can you please explain it with my given code. That will help alot. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `excelImportDBEntities` variable is of type `SqlConnection`, it has `Database` property. That property returns a **string** - the name of the database this connection connects to. Of course, you can't  get `.Connection` from the database name and you get compilation error when you try to.

Then, how to fix it. Your `BulkWriter`'s `InsertAsync` method expects `SqlConnection` object here and you already have this object, `excelImportDBEntities`. Why not using it directly? Replace

```
await new BulkWriter().InsertAsync(usersList, "bomStructuredImportTgt", excelImportDBEntities.Database.Connection, CancellationToken.None);
```

with

```
await new BulkWriter().InsertAsync(usersList, "bomStructuredImportTgt", excelImportDBEntities, CancellationToken.None);
```

and this error should be gone.

Another issue is that, as mentioned in other answers and comments, you seem to mishandle your connection string, which will produce an error after you compile and run your code.

Comment: I have tried to pass my connection string in this way now,    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dev_Purchasing_New_ModelEntities"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection excelImportDBEntities = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {

                await new BulkWriter().InsertAsync(usersList, "bomStructuredImportTgt", excelImportDBEntities, CancellationToken.None);
            }

Comment: The error is gone now However its still not working. Thanks I will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dev_Purchasing_New_ModelEntities"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection excelImportDBEntities = new SqlConnection(connectionString)){
   ...
}
```

Comment: string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dev_Purchasing_New_ModelEntities"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection excelImportDBEntities = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
               
                await new BulkWriter().InsertAsync(usersList, "bomStructuredImportTgt", ((excelImportDBEntities).Database.Connection), CancellationToken.None);
            }

Comment: Have you tried to debug this? What is the value of `connectionString` variable? Do you have a valid connection string in your config?

Comment: Yes I have a valid connection string in Webconfig in the name of Dev_Purchasing_New_ModelEntities